# "Как на зло"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли оборот "как на зло" запятой, если стоит в начале слова? А то что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание как назло является вводным, выражает эмоциональную окраску того, о чем сообщается. Поэтому запятыми выделяется, как и другие вводные слова и словосочетания. Если стоит в начале предложения - тоже.